# JavaStreamingContext.stop() inside onBatchCompleted() throws Cannot stop SparkContext within listener thread of SparkListenerBus

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need to stop the spark gracefully once I find some marker file in hdfs location . I am trying to check for this marker file after each batch completed.

I tried to stop sparkcontext gracefully using ssc.stop(true,true) once it find marker file exists in the predefined hdfs location

```
JavaStreamingContext ssc ;
ssc.addStreamingListener(new SparkGracefulShutDownListener());
....
....


In SparkGracefulShutDownListener implements StreamingListener {
@Override
public void onBatchCompleted(StreamingListenerBatchCompleted 
batchCompleted) {
try {
   ......Performing some operations....
   .......
  if (checkForShutDownMarker()) {
    ssc.stop(true,true);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("Error ", e);
}

}
}
```

checkForShutDownMarker returns true if file exists , then i get below exception when it executes ssc.stop(true,true) line

Exception:

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot stop StreamingContext within listener thread of SparkListenerBus
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot stop StreamingContext within listener thread of SparkListenerBus
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.stop(StreamingContext.scala:662)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.stop(StreamingContext.scala:662)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.stop(JavaStreamingContext.scala:601)

Questions:
How do i stop sparkcontext gracefully when markerfile exists and this check for file should happen after each onbatchCompleted()

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want, my suggestion is not to set stop in instance of JobListener because is not correct and you get this exception, but try use a accumulator variable (Boolean in this case) [Accumulator description](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#accumulators-broadcast-variables-and-checkpoints) that you set true in JobListener's method batchCompleted and use this variable to set true 
or false in stop method.